# Undestanding what unpack('!6s6sH' , bytes(xxxxx)) do - Pyhton

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I'm trying to understand the arguments of the `unpack('!6s6sH' , bytes(eth_header))` function do. I know the unpack function converts the structure to an integer, but what does the '!6s6sH' argument mean?

Comment: did you check documentation for module `struct`? There is table which explains all symbols

Answer (score 0):

You should simply read documetation for `struct`.

There are tables which explain all symbols:

- [format characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters)
- [byte-order-size-and-alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

`!` - byte order `big-endian`

`s` - char[]  (`6s` array for 6 chars)

`H` - unsigned short (integer) (2 bytes)